# Checking if videos from youtube can be used embeded

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube

In a site I have multiple Youtube embedded videos, (with permission) at that time.

Later, after 1-2 years, some of the videos are marked as Youtube only, or are deleted from youtube.

I'm looking for a way to use python:
- to see which video from a list are still available, 
- which can be used embedded
- is a video or playlist

If a package exist, better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#properties) should return to you whether a video is embeddable or not:

Calling on their [video endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/#Videos) should return you a representation that includes:

```
  "status": {
    ...
    "embeddable": boolean,
    "publicStatsViewable": boolean
  },
```

You can use any library you like to hit the API like [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html)